# Setting NSNumber to NSManagedObject attribute

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

I have Entity with attribute "id" in my model with data type integer 64.
I m using property `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * id;` for it. 
I create NSManagedObject using

```
id tempItem = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"XYZ" 
                inManagedObjectContext:context];
```

and setting NSNumber myID value `[tempItem setValue:myID forKey:@"id"];`

Problem is: when I print NSNumber myID using print description it shows me correct number but when I set it to my `NSManagedObject` using the code above and print NSManagedObject it goes into negative value.
I'm trying to set `12941051589483540916` (this number is a valid `interger64`), which gets set to `-5505692484226010700`.

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what about convert NSNumber to NSString and set it to NSManagedObject

Comment: if you're on iPhone (and maybe iPad too) it's 32 bits platform I don't think you can store an int bigger than the 32bit max int. even if you set integer64.

Comment: @NicolasManzini: Core Data can store 64-bit numbers without problems on iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`12941051589483540916` is not a valid "Integer 64". It is greater than

```
2^63 - 1 = 9223372036854775807
```

and therefore does not fit into the range of a *signed* 64-bit number.

Core Data "Integer 64" is a signed 64-bit number, therefore

```
12941051589483540916 = 0xB397D9DB232BB1B4
```

is interpreted as negative number `-5505692484226010700`.

If you know that the values stored in the managed object should represent unsigned quantities,
you have to cast them to an unsigned type, e.g.

```
uint64_t theId = [[tempItem valueForKey:@"id"] unsignedLongLongValue];
```

Comment: I thought thats unsigned so considered 2^64 -1 as range.. uint64_t theId = [[tempItem valueForKey:@"id"] unsignedLongLongValue]; is way but i will now prefer storing as string. Thanks !!

Answer (score 2):

It is a very bad idea use `id` as property name. `id` is a type, namely a generic pointer to a generic object and I think that this create more than one issue, now or in the future.

In Core Data, I usually create the unique identifier property with the following format ID, i.e. for the class Post i will have `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *postID;`